# remove class of group of links once another link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, selector, removeclass

These group of links are my nav elements. `var make_button_active` removes and inserts class active once clicked into the link. With CSS, class active assigns an orange color to the text of the link. I have another link which is outside of this group. Its a logo as link which goes to `#home`. I would like that once this is clicked the class active is removed from the links inside the `ul.menu`. This way the nav elements wont remain colored in orange when #home is clicked. I've tried it alone but I'm a beginner with javascript.

Could you help me with this quest?

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="#home" class="panel"><img src="_img/logo.png" alt="DR logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="categories">
        <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#aboutMe">ABOUT ME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#showcase">SHOWCASE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#howWork">HOW DO I WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#meet">LETS MEET</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </div>
    <hr>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu li.active a {
     color: #ff530d;
}​
```

**JQUERY:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
         var make_button_active = function()
           {
              //Get item siblings
              var siblings =($(this).siblings());
              //Remove active class on all buttons
              siblings.each(function (index)
                {
                  $(this).removeClass('active');
                }
              );

              //Add the clicked button class
              $(this).addClass('active');
            }

        var classOut = function()
            {
                $(".menu li").removeClass('active');
            }


             $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".menu li").click(make_button_active);

            $("#home").click(classOut);
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rewrote your entire JavaScript, does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/C4fwV/4/) help?

I changed your JavaScript to:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $('.menu a').click(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.menu a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');        
  });

  $('#logo > a').click(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.menu a').removeClass('active');        
  });    

});
```

​

Comment: It does!! Exactly what I needed! I understand it but except the following: $('#logo > a').click(function(e). I don understand what ">" sign means in this context, could you explain?

Comment: @Daniel you should not use `e.preventDefault()` if you want the script to jump to the according anchor.

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero the > sign means the child of that element. So it only selects direct child elements not every element further down the tree.

Comment: Adding .not(this) to the remove class would work better, then you wouldn't need an AddClass.

Answer (score 3):

At first: `jQuery !== JavaScript`

Also, `#home` wont select your home link, because it does not select the href, but the id.

Use instead `$("#logo a").click(classOut);`

Also, your function `make_button_active` should look something like this:

```
var make_button_active = function() {
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

You don't need to iterate over all the siblings, your `active` can only be on one element at once, you can just select this and remove the class before setting it on the newly selected element.

Finally, you do not necessarily have to do a **function expression** `var make_button_active = function(){...}`, a **function declaration** is completely okay in your case: `function make_button_active(){...}`. However, often it is good to use function, and not like Sam did using anonymous functions, because you can then reuse those functions easily.

Your entire script should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function make_button_active(){
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    function classOut(){
        $(".menu li").removeClass('active');
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".menu li").click(make_button_active);
        $("#logo a").click(classOut);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I just changed javascrit to Jquery. I dont see the difference so clearly. Thanks for the clearence on how to use variables or functions.

Comment: Javascript is a programming language, and jQuery is a framework built with Javascript to make some common tasks easier.

Comment: @Daniel Also, in javascript you should not put your `{` onto a newline, because this will lead to some nasty errors when used with return statements.

Comment: I had no idea!!! Thanks for that advise!!! I thought that didnt influence too much.

Answer (score 1):

There is no element with ID of `home` in your markup:

```
<a href="#home" id='home' class="panel"><img src="_img/logo.png" alt="DR logo" /></a>
```

You are using ID selector and your selector doesn't select the element with `#home` href attribute. You can add ID to your  element or use attribute selector:

```
$("a[href='#home']").click(classOut);
```

Also you don't need to use `each` method:

```
var make_button_active = function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
}
var classOut = function() {
    $(".menu li").removeClass('active');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu li").click(make_button_active);
    $("#home").click(classOut);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hJdXU/

Comment: I like the oneliner in your function. And it probably is faster then selecting `$("active")` I guess?

Comment: @Christoph Thanks I like your comprehensive answer too, yes, it's faster as we have a reference to the element by using `$(this)`.